# Не могу вывести объект из NSDictionary

Tags: macos, objective-c, xcode

Есть код:

```
NSDictionary *myLibrary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"null", @"0", nil];
NSString *stroka = "@20";
```

Я хочу прочитать второй элемент *stroka* (0) и вывести, соответствующий этому ключю, объект из *myLibrary* (т.е. null):

```
[myLibrary objectForKey:[stroka characterAtIndex:1]];
```

Компилятор ругается из-за того что *characterAtIndex* возвращает *unichar*, а методу *objectForKey* нужен *NSString*. Как выйти из положения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В предыдущем вопросе я предлагал вам метод substringWithRange:, потому что он возвращает строку (NSString), а не C-строку.

У вас два варианта:

1) Использовать substringWithRange: (как я предложил вам в предыдущем вопросе), и тогда objectForKey: будет получать сразу NSString-строку.

2) Или использовать такую конструкцию:

```
NSString *characterAtIndex1AsString = [NSString stringWithCString:[stroka characterAtIndex:1] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[myLibrary objectForKey:characterAtIndex1AsString];
```

Можете попробовать также короткую форму:

```
[myLibrary objectForKey:@([stroka characterAtIndex:1])];
```

Этот второй способ хуже, потому что в этом случае нужно сходить туда-обратно: NSString->char->NSString.

---

Я рекомендую именно первый способ, так как вы будете всё время работать на уровне NSString (то есть на уровне Objective-C) и не опускаться при этом ниже на уровень C-строк. Возможно, способ работы со строками, как с объектами, вам сейчас кажется немного странным, но со временем вы привыкнете, и для вас наоборот будет казаться странным делать перевод частей строки NSString в char и обратно.

Comment: Думаю что должен согласиться с тобой и по мере возможности избегать использования С-строк.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
 [myLibrary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", [stroka characterAtIndex:1]]];
```